# Use same values from array in different drop down menus

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making this hotel booking `form`, or atleast trying to make it work.
But on my road to complete that goal, I've encountered a couple of problems.
I got two different `drop-down menu's`that I want to retrive info from the same `array`, as both will contain the same information.

If anything that I've said seems unclear or to broad, please ask before complaining and I will do my best to explain.

EDIT: The two menus I'm talking about are the two with the value "selectRom".

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>

        </style>

        <title>

        </title>

    </head>

    <body>


    <div>
    <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Velg ett sted</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type="number">
    <br><select id="selectRom">
    <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>

    <br>    <select id="selectRom">
    <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>
    <br>Skipass:<input type="checkbox" id="skiPass">
    <br>Skiutstyr:<input type="checkbox" id="skiUtstyr">




    </div>

    <script>
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
    var options = ["Konsberg", "Trysil", "Beitostølen"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    }
    var select = document.getElementById("selectRom");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    }   

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aditional question, not related to main question, if anyone know how to make this entire thing into a calculator, calculating depending on what info is typed in, I would be greatful if anyone would be kind enough to explain or try to teach me.
**JSFIDDLE:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/wa1fyLa7/

Comment: It's horrible coding practice to use an identical `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: Instead of complaining over someone whom are new to this, could you provide constructiv feedback.

Comment: It's not complaining, it's against standard and possibly causes errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/wa1fyLa7/5/

Note :please dont use the same id for multiple times.

```
<body>


    <div>
    <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Velg ett sted</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type="number">
    <br><select id="selectRom">
    <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>

    <br>    <select id="selectRom2">
    <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>
    <br>Skipass:<input type="checkbox" id="skiPass">
    <br>Skiutstyr:<input type="checkbox" id="skiUtstyr">




    </div>

    <script>
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
    var options = ["Konsberg", "Trysil", "Beitostølen"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    }
    var select = document.getElementById("selectRom");  
  var select2 = document.getElementById("selectRom2");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
     var el2 = document.createElement("option");
    el2.textContent = opt;
    el2.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    select2.appendChild(el2);
    }   

    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed :)

Comment: happy coding @ImNewToThis

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/wa1fyLa7/1/

I changed the elem to class and not id.

```
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName("selectRom");
  console.log(select);
  var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
  for(var j = 0; j < select.length; j++) {
  var elem = select[j];
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      elem.appendChild(el);
    }   

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted to do this

```html
<body>


  <div>
    <select id="selectNumber">
      <option>Velg ett sted</option>
    </select>
    <input type="date">
    <input type="number">
    <br>
    <select id="selectRom">
      <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <select id="selectRom2">
      <option>Antall singel rom</option>
    </select>
    <br>Skipass:
    <input type="checkbox" id="skiPass">
    <br>Skiutstyr:
    <input type="checkbox" id="skiUtstyr">




  </div>

  <script>
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
    var options = ["Konsberg", "Trysil", "Beitostølen"];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var opt = options[i];
      var el = document.createElement("option");
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
    }
    add("selectRom");
    add("selectRom2");

    function add(idN) {
        var select = document.getElementById(idN);
        var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          var opt = options[i];
          var el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = opt;
          el.value = opt;
          select.appendChild(el);
        }
      }
      //var select = document.getElementById("selectRom");
      //var options = ["1", "2", "3"];
      //for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      //var opt = options[i];
      //var el = document.createElement("option");
      //el.textContent = opt;
      //el.value = opt;
      //select.appendChild(el);
      //}
  </script>
</body>
```